# How to summon an invisible armor stand with a diamond sword with a damage value and unbreaking on it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can I get some help on summon an invisible armor stand with a diamond sword on its head with the damage value being 944 and unbreaking on it?
In the 1.12.2 format.
The command I've been trying to use and have only being getting an invulnerable floating diamond sword on the head of the armor stand is:
 `/summon armorstand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",Damage:944b,Unbreakable:1b,Count:1b}]}`

Answer (score 1):

This will be the correct command:

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,
ArmorItems:[{},{},{},{id:"diamond_sword",Count:1b,Damage:944,tag:{ench:[{id:34,lvl:3}]}}]}
```

By placing the sword in the head slot a player can't grab the item, if you'd like to make the sword grabable you can use this command:

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~1 ~ {Invisible:1b,Invulnerable:1b,ShowArms:1b,
HandItems:[{id:"diamond_sword",Count:1b,Damage:944,tag:{ench:[{id:34,lvl:3}]}},{}]}
```